# Not able to set source of an imageview in Included layout in an activity

Tags: android, include, android-imageview

I have created two XML layout and Activity respecively.

1. A XML file A contains a  layout with Image view Pointed to Activity A.
2. A XML file B, in that i included XML A and made Activity B extends Acitivity A
   In Acivity A oncreate i set the image source for the XML file A. but its not setting the image source and not getting any error also. Plz help me

Here is my code
Xml A

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/MasterBaseLayOut"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />   
</RelativeLayout>
```

XML B

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/Master"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/xmlA" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:onClick="btn1_onclick"
        android:text="@string/title_1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity A

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.XMLA);
    ImageButton img1 =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);

    img1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgtest);

}
}
```

Activity B

```
public class ActivityB extends ActivityA {


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.XmlB);

        }
}
```

Comment: In addition to your explanation, also post the most relevant code.

Comment: can you post some more code?

Answer (score 0):

Tough you have no code, but i assume you are not getting the imageView in Activity B.So in Activity 
B's onCreate() method call the Activity A's onCreate using super keyword,most probably you will get the imageview with source image.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
super.onCreate(b);
}
```

Comment: I checked in debug mode activity A oncreate runs first then only acitivty B oncreate gets run....

Comment: ok.So u r not getting the image source that u set on activity A while running Activity B.That is the case right ?

Comment: S, i kept acitvity B as start up .

Answer (score 0):

This is what you have:

**ActivityA extends ActivityB**

This is what it should be:

**ActivityB extends ActivityA**

Also, you should consider pressing "Ctrl + Shift + F" to format your code, just a little tip.